# Javascript: it's the instance name known to the constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor, instance

I have a

```
var code = new CodeObject();
```

is there a way to get the name of the instance ("code" in the example) inside the CodeObject function?

something like:

```
function CodeObject() {
    this.id = this.instanceName;
}
```

thanks in advance

I know that in general the thing is really unpredictable, but mine is a really specific case where the constructor is always called in the way shown above.

And I would need it because I want to use the name of the instance without having to pass it to the constructor to avoid repetition of chars (the JSP file that contains the calls is too big already).

Comment: Definitely not. Also, what if you did `array.push(new CodeObject())` -- what would the name be then? If you want the object to have a name, then pass the name as a constructor parameter.

Comment: Just curious, why would you need it? the _this_ pointer is a reference to the object itself

Comment: That kind of introspection is not possible.

Comment: A variable refers to e.g. an object, but an object is not bound to one variable. You can store it at numerous places (variables, properties), or even use it on the fly without storing it.

Comment: @AshwiniKhare: This can be needed to pass variable name to Flash movie (since object itself cannot be passed to Flash movie) that could later use this name to call a JS function or to alter the JS variable value.

Answer (score 0):

```
function hello() {
  var name = /function ([^\(]+)/.exec(this.constructor)[0];
  alert(name);
}
```

Comment: This gives the arguments of the constructor. What the OP wants is the *name* of the *variable* where the instance is stored